# Calling the onCreateOptionsMenu() for the actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock

I have set the `login` on the action item as shown in the below image. Whenever user clicks on login, `login screen` would be displayed. Whenever user enters credentials and logged in I am finishing the loginActivity and redirecting it to other screen, besides I am also replacing the Login with the `name of the user` on the actionbar.

1. Whenever user clicks back button it goes back to homepage which shows again `login`, but not `username` on the action bar. So, how can I change this.
2. Whenever user clicks on his username a **dropdown list** is shown in which **logout** option is there. Whenever user clicks on logout option, I want to update the actionbar with **login** option, but it shows the username still.

Can someone please help me solve these two problems? Code snippets are appreciated.

```
public abstract class HomeActivity extends SherlockActivity {
    protected static boolean mIsLoginButton = false;
    protected static String user_name = "";
    protected static boolean mIsUserLoggedIn = false;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

         if(mIsLoginButton)
         {
            menu.add("Login")
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
         }

         else if(mIsUserLoggedIn)
         {


                SubMenu subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu(user_name);

                subMenu1.add(0, 3 , 0, "Log out");

                MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();

                subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

         }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId())
        {

        case 0:
            if(mIsLoginButton)
            {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }

            return true;


        case 3:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked on logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  // Case 3 which is logout condition. So what should I do here to update the current activity.

            LogManager.logoutUser();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` whenever you want to "refresh" your `optionsMenu` that should do the trick. invalidateOptionsMenu() starts calling `onCreateOptionsMenu` for each menu in play in the hierarchy.